# EditText custom background

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext

My question is quite short and simple but I'm unable to find a solution. I wan to make my `EditText` looks like this form:

[image]

So, every time the user input a char (`android:inputType="numberDecimal"`), it goes to the next box. (Just display the char into next box no need to display the cursor). It would be nice if this could be done using a single `EditBox`.

I have no other idea than making 5 liniar `EditText` controls and add `TextWatcher` to every one of it forcing it to jump (`focus`) to the next one. But this seems a less elegant solution and more complex.

Has anyone any other ideea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just checkout here https://github.com/Philio/PinEntryView as you required **"Just display the char into next box no need to display the cursor".**

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel everytime. I guess **[this](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3764)** has exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your solution works but I chose the solution of @Raju since it ofers more control for the customization.